# Problems with v.split.length in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm taking a course in Qgis and I've come up in a problem I can't figure out.

I'm supposed to split a line in to segments with the v.split.lenght tool.
But when I do this there is no new layer coming up. 
It runs the process but then nothing happenes.

Anyone got an idea why this keeps happening?
Using Qgis  version  2.18.

Comment: Hi and welcome to gis.se. Could add a screenshot of the v.split.length settings you're using to your question? That might help to solve your issue.